# I want to place a button on a background image

Tags: css, button, background-image

I have a button that I was to put on top of my background image, but whenever I put it down it fills the whole screen. Could someone show me how to put it at the top left of the page? https://www.codecademy.com/byteSurfer77914/codebits/cV0Szc/edit

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your button anywhere, but look at a few of my comments in your code and you should get an idea of where to start modifying your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<p> <!--you can't have a p tag in the <head>-->
</p>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body><p2><!--No such thing as a p2 tag-->
</p2>
</body>
</html>
```

Now your CSS

```
body {
    background-image: url('http://i.ytimg.com/vi/E_gnIn3IBdI/maxresdefault.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
//You have multiple body tags.  So your css above is being overwritten by this next block. You probably want this to be assigned to an a tag or a button.
body {
  display:       inline-block;
  padding:       8px 13px;
  background:    #073763 url('http://dabuttonfactory.com/button.png?w=1&h=42&bgt=gradient&bgc=f40808&ebgc=073763') repeat-x;
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(#f40808, #073763);
  background:    -o-linear-gradient(#f40808, #073763);
  background:    -webkit-linear-gradient(#f40808, #073763);
  background:    linear-gradient(#f40808, #073763);
  border-radius: 8px;
  color:         #fff;
  font:          normal 400 26px/1 "Pacifico", cursive;
  text-align:    center;
  text-shadow:   1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```